# can't draw the grouped value above stacked bar plot in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a ggplot2 question, I run the code below show the stacked barplot without add value above each bar correctly:

```
p=ggplot(data=essnn) 
  p+geom_bar(binwidth=0.5,stat="identity")+  #
  aes(x=reorder(classname,-amount,sum), y=amount, label=amount, fill = sort(year))+
  theme()
```

[image: picture]

I want add the sum amount grouped by year in each class, and here is my code:

`+geom_text(aes(x=classes,y=total,label=total), data=essnnta, fill=NULL, size=3)`

But an error message appear:

```
Error in fill = year, can not find object "year"
```

That's my problem: **why the object "year" can be found when I draw stack bar plot without add the sum amount grouped by year in each class, but when I add the sum amount grouped by year, the error appear**?

```
> str(essnn)
    'data.frame':   48619 obs. of  15 variables:
     $ id       : int  2006051337 2006051337 2006051337 2006051337 2006051337 2006051337 2004070648 2006031360 2006031360 2004070062 ...
     $ gender   : Factor w/ 3 levels "","F","M": 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 ...
     $ age      : num  30 30 30 30 30 30 38 43 43 37 ...
     $ class    : Factor w/ 92 levels "100ab","100aa",..: 18 18 18 18 18 18 18 18 18 18 ...
     $ classname: Factor w/ 1136 levels "cad"," Office2010",..: 111 111 111 111 111 111 116 107 107 107 ...
     $ grade    : num  7 5 6 8 3 4 1 4 3 2 ...
     $ year     : Factor w/ 6 levels "98","99","100",..: 3 3 3 3 2 2 4 5 5 3 ...
     $ ses      : num  212 210 211 213 207 208 217 221 220 210 ...
     $ date     : int  1010421 1001115 1010214 1010701 1000411 1000627 1020424 1030304 1021121 1001108 ...
     $ money    : num  5800 5800 5800 5800 5200 5200 3000 0 5500 5500 ...
     $ discount : num  1160 1160 1160 1160 1040 1040 600 0 275 550 ...
     $ amount   : num  4640 4640 4640 4640 4160 ...
     $ idc      : Factor w/ 7 levels "在校生","校友",..: 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 7 7 7 ...
     $ mdy      : Date, format: "2012-04-21" "2011-11-15" "2012-02-14" "2012-07-01" ...
     $ day      : num  1123 1281 1190 1052 1499 ...

> str(essnnta)
        'data.frame':   10 obs. of  2 variables:
         $ classes: Factor w/ 10 levels "JD","JF",..: 1 7 8 4 6 10 3 5 2 9
         $ total  : num  55603526 43708950 43555010 35649129 33214372 ...
```

Comment: Try adding `essnnta$year = NA` to the `essnnta` data frame and see if the code works. Also, I don't think you need `fill=NULL` in the call to `geom_text`.

Comment: thanks for your common, but still not work.

Comment: You might be looking for `inherit.aes = FALSE` when you add `geom_text`.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem might be that your x-axes are not the same in the two data frames. So ggplot does not know which value corresponds with which stack. I am not sure about this as I don't understand the way you define your x axis in the original barplot. I also find it a bit strange to define the aes outside of the ggplot function or the geom_bar. But that might just be me be used to a different kind of syntax. 
All in all I find it difficult to help you as you do not provide any reproducible example.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a small bit of data, and a plot that sort of works.  If you supplement your question with your data (or a subset of it), see if this works.  You may also want to position the label at the top of each bar.

```
essnn <- data.frame(year = c(98,99,100,101,102),
                    classname = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e"),
                    amount = c(1e6, 2e6,3e6,4e6,5e6))
essnnta <- data.frame(total = c(10, 20, 30, 40, 50))

ggplot(data=essnn, aes(x=reorder(classname,-amount, sum), y=amount, fill = year)) +
  geom_bar(binwidth=0.5, stat="identity", position = "stack") +
  geom_text(aes(x=essnn$classname, y=essnnta$total, label=essnnta$total), size=3) # not "classes"
```

[image]